# Display Loading Icon on Route Resolver / Route Change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

Im trying to show a loading icon while I the `route resolver` gets the data from the DB.

**I've tried the below option:**

**Root Component:**

```
_router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: RouterEvent) => {

   if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      console.log("start");
      this.loading = true;

   } else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationError || NavigationCancel || NavigationEnd) {
    console.log("end");
    this.loading = false;
  }

});
```

**Root Component HTML:**

```
<h1 *ngIf="loading">Loading</h1>
```

**The loading icon does not show at all.**

The following is displayed on console log on every route change:

[image]

**Update:**

Below is the output after applying the following changes:

```
 public loading: boolean = true;

 console.log(routerEvent);

 console.log("Loading is " + this.loading);
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="uk-offcanvas-content">
  <h1>{{loading}}</h1>
  <h1 *ngIf="loading">Loading</h1>

  <app-root-nav></app-root-nav>

  <app-notifications></app-notifications>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from "../../authentication/services/authentication.service";
import {Router, Event, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError} from "@angular/router";

import {RouterEvent} from "@angular/router";
import UIkit from 'uikit'

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })

 export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  public loading: boolean = true;
  UIkit: any;

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _authService: AuthenticationService) {

  _router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: RouterEvent) => {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {

      this.loading = true;
      console.log(routerEvent);
      console.log("Loading is " + this.loading);

  } else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationError || NavigationCancel || NavigationEnd) {

    this.loading = false;
  }
});
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
}

ngOnInit() {

  UIkit.notification({
    message: 'my-message!',
    status: 'primary',
    pos: 'top-right',
    timeout: 5000
  });

 }

}
```

Comment: Could you initialize `public loading: boolean = true`, instead of setting it to `true` in `NavigationStart`? Another suggestion: make `loading` a property and put `console.log("loading is ", value)` in the setter, to see if its value is changed when appropriate.

Comment: One more suggestion: put `console.log(routerEvent)` at the start of the callback, to see if you catch all the appropriate events.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thank you for the comments. I've applied the suggestions you provided. Unfortunately still no luck. Please see my updated question for more details.

Comment: my guess is that your local server is responding with the data too quickly. try artificially slowing it down by putting .delay(3000) in the resolve observable.

Comment: @bryan60 still no luck my friend. Just tried your suggestion. This ones really getting to me.

Comment: If you initialize `loading` to `true` initially, and change it only in the constructor with `setTimeout(() => { this.loading = false; }, 10000);`, do you see the loading message for a few seconds? Another question: do you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I don't see the message even after setting the timeout. And no Im not using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. I also noticed something. I placed `{{loading}}` within the html to see whether the value changes. But it doesn't. It's always **false**

Comment: Is `loading` a variable or a property of the same component as the template that contains the loading message? And what if you set `loading = true;` and never change it? Do you see the message?

Comment: @ConnorsFan `loading` is a variable of the same component as the template. Both belong to the root `app.component.ts`

Comment: If `loading` is always `true`, do you see the message?

Comment: Or if you remove `*ngIf` completely, do you see the message?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I can see the message if `loading` is always set to true. And can also see the message if I remove `*ngIf`

Comment: @ConnorsFan please see my updated question. It includes all the code for both class and template.

Comment: I recreated this issue in a plunk. The issue is how you're detecting the navigation end event. answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is pretty simple but easy to miss. you're improperly checking for the router event type, it should be like :

```
else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationError || routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel || routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd)
```

the way you have it is just returning true always because your second clause is  basically "or if NavigationCancel is truthy", which it is by definition since it's an existing type.  so loading sets to false immediately when the route resolve starts since there are a lot of intermediate router events before NavigationEnd event and it sets to false on all of them due to the way you're checking.

plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/7UKVqKlRY0EPXNkx0qxH?p=preview

Comment: I can't believe how I missed that. Sometimes its the simple things that make you go crazy. Thanks for the help buddy. Really Appreciate it. p.s I have to wait 3 hours before I can award the bounty for some reason. I'll do it soon.

Comment: that's the truth, has happened to me countless times and this one was real easy to overlook, as evidenced by the 4-5 devs who missed it including me at first. I didn't even realize it till I started logging all the router events that set loading to false in the plunkr and realized that every router event except start was setting it to false, then checked the clauses and it hit me. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to show a loading icon while the route resolver gets the data from the DB :

```
 constructor(private router: Router){
          router.events.subscribe(e => {
                if (e instanceof ChildActivationStart) {
                      this.loaderservice.show();
                 } else if (e instanceof ChildActivationEnd) {
                      this.loaderservice.hide();
                  }
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd similar situation and i resolved in the following way:

```
  public loading = true;

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  public onClick(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.router.navigate(['/test']).then(_ => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

I managed navigation in the programmatically way. I put loading variable to `true` before start navigation and i switch its value to `false` when routing is finished.